# How to modity the Right-Click menu for the File Explorer address bar

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Can you modify this Right-Click menu?

Here is an example of the menu I'm talking about -

[image]

I have wanted the ability to modify the right-click menu within File Explorer, to add 'Open Command Prompt Here' (Cmd.exe) and 'Bash Prompt Here...' (Cygwin) for the longest time when you right click on the address bar in File Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With very advanced programming, it is possible, albeit very difficult. If you want the programming term, it involves installing a hook!

But if you are looking for a Microsoft-supported way – one that you can implement by changing Registry or such – no!

Comment: bummer, that was exactly what I was thinking - possible down deep, but not in the normal way (regedit)!